# How does the following test pass?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple test for the following controller action method

Admin controller

```
namespace TestingDemo {

    public class AdminController : Controller {
        private IUserRepository repository;

        public AdminController(IUserRepository repo) {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ActionResult ChangeLoginName(string oldName, string newName) {
            User user = repository.FetchByLoginName(oldName);
            user.LoginName = newName;
            repository.SubmitChanges();
            // render some view to show the result
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The test I have is this

```
namespace TestingDemo.Tests {

    [TestClass]
    public class AdminControllerTests {

        [TestMethod]
        public void CanChangeLoginName() {

            // Arrange (set up a scenario) 
            User user = new User() { LoginName = "Bob" };
            FakeRepository repositoryParam = new FakeRepository();
            repositoryParam.Add(user);
            AdminController target = new AdminController(repositoryParam);
            string oldLoginParam = user.LoginName;
            string newLoginParam = "Joe";

            // Act (attempt the operation) 
            target.ChangeLoginName(oldLoginParam, newLoginParam);

            // Assert (verify the result) 
            Assert.AreEqual(newLoginParam, user.LoginName);
            Assert.IsTrue(repositoryParam.DidSubmitChanges);
        }
    }

    class FakeRepository : IUserRepository {
        public List<User> Users = new List<User>();
        public bool DidSubmitChanges = false;

        public void Add(User user) {
            Users.Add(user);
        }

        public User FetchByLoginName(string loginName) {
            return Users.First(m => m.LoginName == loginName);
        }

        public void SubmitChanges() {
            DidSubmitChanges = true;
        }
    }
}
```

my question is how does user.LoginName get changed?  the only change that happens to user is in the  action method, and that is a local user variable.  How is the user variable in the test getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

The controller test first adds a user to `List<User> Users` in the fake repository, using the `Users.Add` method.

The repository this is added to is passed into the constructor of the controller in the test:
`AdminController target = new AdminController(repositoryParam);`

Comment: Yep I get those, but the user is declared in the test.   User user = new User() { LoginName = "Bob" };  How is this getting updated? I am not passing the user variable as a parameter.  All I am passing is the  user.LoginName to the action method

Comment: you added the user to the repository, which is passed into the AdminController.  The AdminController's method (ChangeLoginName) uses the repository you passed in, which has user 'Joe'.  This user is found because you search for the user by name on the repository. You then set the new name on that user object.  The `List` in the repository still has a reference to the memory address for the user whose name has been changed, and that's why the name change works.

Comment: Thanks.  So even in the ChangeLoginName when I create a new variable to hold the user I find called 'Bob'.  When I change the properties in that variable the List gets changed as well?  Are there any tutorials on this somewhere? I just want to do some further reading.  It just seems confusing when you make a change and suddenly its already reflected automatically, when I don't explicitly tell it to do so.  sorry might sound like a noob thing to say...